# In Android Chrome, intent user into Google Maps app (instead of app selection popup) and then turn-by-turn directions?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-chrome, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

In Android, I'm trying to have a user go straight into Google Maps (ideally even into the turn-by-turn directions mode) through a link in our web app running in Android Chrome.

This is important because we're developing an applications for users in Kenya, and as many users are new to Android, they often get confused by the application selection screen the open a general maps.google.com link in Chrome, Browser, or Google Maps.

I've tried to use the [Android Chrome Intents documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) to figure this out, but have at best gotten to:

```
  <a href="intent://#Intent;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;action=com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity;end;">Open gmaps</a>
```

but this just opens the Play Store showing the Google Maps app, not the Google Maps app itself.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this eventually?

Comment: no, we didn't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set your scheme to 'geo' as well as the URI you would like to launch. This can be done by:

```
intent://maps.google.com/geo:0,0?q=ADDRESS_SEPARATED_BY_PLUS_SIGNS;/#Intent;scheme=geo;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end;
```